Why Did Ramban Write His Own Commentary on Massekhet Nedarim Instead of Annotating the Rif’s Commentary?
Why did Ramban write a commentary on Massekhet Nedarim that closely follows the general approach of the Rif, even though there was already a commentary on the Rif he could have annotated directly?

The printed work attributed to the Rif on Nedarim isn't actually by the Rif. Rabbi Yaakov Chayyim Sofer gives the following proofs (Tzefunot 7 p. 77, which I found quoted here):

The Ramban wouldn't have authored his own Halachot if the Rif had already done so. Since he made extensive research to interpret the Rif and even checked the Rif's autograph, it couldn't be that he simply didn't have a copy of the Rif on an entire tractate if it existed.

None of the early rishonim mention the Rif on Nedarim.

What is known of the Rif doesn't align with the work on Nedarim. A citation of the Rif in the Tur doesn't appear in the printed Rif on Nedarim, and the Rashba says the Rif omitted something that does appear in the printed Rif on Nedarim.



That in turn kind of brings up a question: why indeed didn't the Rif write on Nedarim, considering that it's applicable nowadays?

@Meir The answer alluded to by Rabbi Sofer, based on the Ramban at the end of Nedarim, is that the laws of Nedarim weren't practically applied, in ordinary circumstances, from Rav Yehudai Gaon onwards
